# VBA - returning CSS formatting values with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, vba

I try to check whether element in the table has float: left or float: right property to determine what element it is related to. Unfortunately

`.getAttribute("Style")`

works only for inline HTML styling, not CSS. My code below doesn't work as getAttribute returns [object MSStyleCSSProperties].

```
Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement
Dim PopUpWindow As Object

For Each htmlele In PopUpWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    If InStr(htmlele.getAttribute("Style"), "float: left;") <> 0 Then
       'do stuff
    End if
Next htmlele
```

Is there a way to work with CSS through VBA at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at `htmlele.style.float`. All styles of an element are available through the [`style` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535870(v=vs.85).aspx).

There are also the [`currentStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703980(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`runtimeStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535889(v=vs.85).aspx) properties (which have subtle differences, check the documentation). They might or might not be available, depending on which version of the `IHTMLElement` interface is implemented by the objects you are dealing with.

`runtimeStyle` and `currentStyle` occur in [`IHTMLElement2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703984(v=vs.85).aspx), the list goes up to `IHTMLElement8`. Use the VBA debugger to see which of the properties you can use and whether they contain the values you expect.

Comment: Looks like only CurrentStyle works with embedded stylesheets, other solutions are all inline only from descriptions and my testing. I can't however understand how "IHTMLCurrentStyle::color" from Microsoft's example could be translated to my VBA code syntax.

Comment: It probably is not translated in any way. I'm not sure what that has to do with your question though, which was about float.

Comment: I hoped it could return float if I used "float" in place of a color, but there are no examples of VBA code that would use it and all testing I did in immediate window while debugging using listed methods returned "Null" or "none" for CSS formatted object.